# How do I rewrite this code without the `var`?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

I have the following code to return a different object depending on the value of the array element at index 1

```js
const myArray = Array(1,2,3)
const myOtherArray = Array(1,3,4) 
const myThirdArray = Array(1,5,7)

// Creates object from array and prints it
let toObject = function(x){
  var myObject
  if (x[1] == 2){
     myObject = {first: x[0],
      second: x[1],
      third: x[2]
    }
  }
  else if (x[1] == 3){
     myObject = {first: x[0],
      second: x[1]-1,
      third: x[2]
    }
  }
  else {
     myObject = {first: x[0],
      second: x[1]+1,
      third: x[2]
    }
  }
  
  return myObject
}

console.log(toObject(myThirdArray))
```

The problem with the above implementation is that I define `myObject` and use an assignment statement. I'd like to implement this in a "purely functional" manner, i.e., avoiding mutability. In Scala or Haskell, I suppose I could use pattern matching, but how would I accomplish this in Javascript? Is it possible to implement this without using `var`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just replace "myObject" with "return" in your if blocks.

Just for fun, here is a completely unreadable way to do it:

```
return { first: x[0],
   second: (x[1]+1) - (x[1] == 2) - 2*(x[1] == 3),
   third: x[2]
};
```

More seriously you might make the logic for "second" a very small function on its own, and call that function.

But you should compose two functions: one to rename the keys and the other to apply the offset to `second`.

Comment: plus you can drop the `else`'s entirely. just keep the second `if`.

Comment: i don't see why trick/gimmick suggestions get actual code whereas more "serious" suggestions just get an english sentence

Comment: @naomik because it was fun to write, impossible to explain without putting it in full, and it tends to grate on me when I have to translate such a sentence as "just replace myObject with return" with a code example too. But it exists in all the other answers if you need it.

Answer (score 2):

Since only difference is the second, you can do it this way

```
let toObject = function(x){
  let offset = 1;
  if (x[1] == 2){
      offset = 0;
  }
  else if (x[1] == 3){
      offset = -1;
  }

  return {first: x[0],
      second: x[1] + offset,
      third: x[2]
    }
}
```

Comment: you can do with out ternary operator as well.. but code will be a bit longer

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using destructuring assignment in place of your functions `x` parameter. Combined with a straightforward `switch`, the resulting function offers a tremendous improvement in readability and style

```js
const toObject = ([first, second, third]) => {
  switch (second) {
    case 2:
      return { first, second, third }
    case 3:
      return { first, second: second - 1, third }
    default:
      return { first, second: second + 1, third }
  }
}

console.log(toObject([ 1, 2, 3 ]))
// => { first: 1, second: 2, third: 3 }

console.log(toObject([ 1, 3, 4 ]))
// => { first: 1, second: 2, third: 4 }

console.log(toObject([ 1, 5, 7 ]))
// => { first: 1, second: 6, third: 7 }
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a really elegant solution. This is more like the pattern matching-based solution I was looking for. I wasn't aware this was possible in ES6.

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of something like this?

```
let toObject = function(x){

  if (x[1] == 2){
     return {first: x[0],
      second: x[1],
      third: x[2]
    };
  }
  else if (x[1] == 3){
     return {first: x[0],
      second: x[1]-1,
      third: x[2]
    };
  }
  else {
     return {first: x[0],
      second: x[1]+1,
      third: x[2]
    };
  }
}
```